# FLTFirebaseMessaging: An error occurred while calling method Messaging#getToken, errorOrNil { NSLocalizedFailureReason = "Too many server requests.";}

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout, firebase-cloud-messaging

I had removed my IOS folder and re-added it with `flutter create . --platforms iOS` .Did this as I was receiving some error and saw this was the solution for it. I tried adding firebase again and I am getting this error:

```
FLTFirebaseMessaging: An error occurred while calling method Messaging#getToken, errorOrNil => {
    NSLocalizedFailureReason = "Too many server requests.";
}
flutter: null
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_messaging/unknown] An unknown error has occurred.
```

I checked my bundleID it matches exactly and I added google service info plist file.
I have to done these steps multiple times but still receive this error.

Any suggestions regarding this will be greatly appreciated.**App working completely fine on android**

Comment: I got the same issue here. Did you solve it in the end?